# Not able to find Android folder to find SDK

Tags: android, sdk

After installing Android studio with sdk I cannot able to find the Android folder inside local folder. What might be the issue?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could specify the OS, installation steps, if android studio working?

Comment: I'am facing error that i cannot specify the path in Android studio so i cannot open the new project and it asks SDK Path and i tried get the path inside AppData/Local but inside Local i don't have folder called Android and kindly help me with solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for that folder, did you get an error? What is the message of that error? 
There is an android folder in c://users/{username}
It might be hidden.

Comment: I'am facing error that i cannot specify the path in Android studio so i cannot open the new project and it asks SDK Path and i tried get the path inside AppData/Local but inside Local i don't have folder called Android and kindly help me with solution. Thanks.